# Poor WAMP performance when using SMB/UNC Paths

Tags: apache-2.2, server-message-block

I've configured a WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL and PHP) stack when when configured to use local storage takes 3-4 seconds to load. When I use an SMB/UNC share it takes 12-15 seconds to load.

Here are the two lines in my httpd.conf:

```
 #DocumentRoot "//10.99.108.11/test_htdocs"
 #<Directory "//10.99.108.11/test_htdocs">

 #DocumentRoot "C:/www"
 #<Directory "C:/www">
```

Is there performance tuning I can do on windows server 2008 R2 to improve performance or is there another way to improve performance using smb

Answer (score 0):

A script that takes 3-4 seconds in PHP must be pretty large, maybe you're using a CMS or other platform. Either way, SMB has far too much lag to be a practical docroot of your site. It's just inherent in the protocol I'm afraid. NFS may be faster, but really, your docroot should be local. I'm actually quite amazed it only takes 12-15 seconds if a local version takes 3-4.

Comment: Is this something specific to Apache, or in general? We have a bunch of sites running in IIS on a DFS root (which is CIFS) and we don't see any appreciable delay in accessing network resources